# Intersection numbers on blow-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, birational-geometry

Let $p:X\to\mathbb A^3$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb A^3$ along a line $L$. Denote the exceptional divisor as $E$. Let $H$ be a plane containing $L$ and $\tilde{H}$ be the strict transform. I found contradiction when computing some intersection numbers.

Let $C=\tilde{H}\cap E$. Then projection formula implies that $$p^*H\cdot C=p_*(p^*H\cdot C)=H\cdot p_*C=H\cdot L=1.$$ The intersections are interpreted as intersections in the Chow ring of $X$ and $\mathbb A^3$.

On the other hand, however, $E\cdot C=0$  since $C$ deforms in $\tilde{H}$ in a ruling and a small perturbation of $C$ is disjoint from the exceptional divisor $E$. Similarly, $\tilde{H}\cdot C=0$ since $C$ can be deformed in $E$ (consider a family of planes $H_t$ containing $L$, their strict transforms on $E$ are disjoint) and a small deformation will be disjoint from $\tilde{H}$.

So $0=E\cdot C+\tilde{H}\cdot C=p^*H\cdot C=1$. Contradiction. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148362/intersection-theory-and-blow-ups).

Comment: Are you sure you want to be on $\mathbb{A}^3$ and not $\mathbb{P}^3$? On $\mathbb{A^3}$ there is no contradiction because the $0$-th Chow group is trivial. That is, 0 times the class of a point equals 1 times the class of a point.

Comment: Anyway, $\tilde H \cdot C = 0$ is correct and $E \cdot C = 0$ is wrong. When you move $C$ in a ruling into $\tilde H$, it will still intersect $E$ in a point. So $E \cdot C = 1$.

Comment: @JakeLevinson Thanks for your comments! They are helpful. Actually, I still want $\mathbb A^3$ instead of $\mathbb P^3$. I can see $E\cdot C=1$ in the $\mathbb P^3$ case, since $\tilde{H}$ becomes $\mathbb P^2$ and two general lines intersect at a point. In the $\mathbb A^3$ case, I was thinking the intersection number being $0$ since the two lines can be chosen to intersect at infinity.

Comment: @JakeLevinson  I realized that maybe I still don't understand the definition of intersection theory on quasi projective varieties. Suppose $X$ is a smooth quasi projective variety, and $D_1$, $D_2$ are subvarieties of complementary dimensions. So what is supposed to be the right definition of $D_1\cdot D_2$? Moving them to general position so they intersect transversely and there is no intersection "at infinity"?

Comment: @AGlearner In general $D_1 \cdot D_2$ should be understood as a rational equivalence class on $X$, an element of the Chow group $A_d(X)$ where $d = \dim(X) - \mathrm{codim}(D_1) - \mathrm{codim}(D_2)$. In the case where $X$ isn't proper, the $0$-th Chow group is trivial, $A_0(X) = 0$. So for the blowup of a line in $\mathbb{A}^3$, there's no contradiction -- your description and my description *both* accurately describe the class $E \cdot C$. It's just that $0$ points is equivalent to $1$ point (exactly because the one point can be moved off to infinity).

Comment: @AGlearner In contrast, when $X$ is proper, there's always a well-defined homomorphism $\deg : A_0(X) \to \mathbb{Z}$ which sends $[p] \mapsto 1$ for all $p \in X$. So it's a common enough abbreviation to write (for example) $\tilde H \cdot C = 1$ when it's understood that this stands for $\deg(\tilde H \cdot C) = 1$.

Comment: @JakeLevinson That's insightful! Thanks a lot!